# Kubernetes Ingress not redirecting to correct path

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a Django application hosted on Apache inside a Kubernetes cluster running as a deployment. The application is running on port 8080 and app root is *"/"*. I want my ingress to redirect to my application when someone enters /tascaty but this is not happening when I enter the path as /tascaty in ingress resource. But when I set path as / it works. Below are the details of my APP

Apache Config File for application:

```html
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>

        WSGIDaemonProcess tascaty_dev python-path=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages

        <Location />
                WSGIProcessGroup tascaty_dev
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        </Location>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tascaty_project/wsgi.py
        <Directory /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tascaty_project/>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        Alias /static /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/static
        <Directory /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

App Deployment :

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tascatyk8s-deployment
  namespace: tascaty
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: tascatyk8s
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: tascatyk8s
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: tascatyk8s-mount
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: tascatyk8s-pvc
      containers:
        - name: tascatyk8s
          image: abdul8423/tascatyk8s:v3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/users/migrations
              name: tascatyk8s-mount
              subPath: users
            - mountPath: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tascaty/migrations
              name: tascatyk8s-mount
              subPath: tascaty
            - mountPath: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/leaves/migrations
              name: tascatyk8s-mount
              subPath: leaves
            - mountPath: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/blog/migrations
              name: tascatyk8s-mount
              subPath: blog
          env:
            - name: TASCATY_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: tascatyk8s-dep-configmap
                  key: TASCATY_HOST
            - name: TASCATY_PORT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: tascatyk8s-dep-configmap
                  key: TASCATY_PORT
            - name: TASCATY_DB
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: tascatyk8s-dep-configmap
                  key: TASCATY_DB
            - name: TASCATY_USER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: tascatyk8s-dep-configmap
                  key: TASCATY_USER
            - name: TASCATY_PASS
              valueFrom: 
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: tascaty-secret
                  key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
      nodeSelector:
        component: tascaty
```

App Service

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tascatyk8s-cluster-ip-service
  namespace: tascaty
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: tascatyk8s
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

Ingress Controller is installed using

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.34.1/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
```

Ingress Resource :

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tascatyk8s-deployment-ingress
  namespace: tascaty
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /tascaty
        backend:
          serviceName: tascatyk8s-cluster-ip-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

When I try to access https://192.168.56.2:31150/tascaty it redirects to https://192.168.56.2:31150/login/?next=/
but I get a *`404 Not Found`*

[image: image1]

But when I replace the path inside the ingress resource with / instead of /tascaty it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What's happening with the ingress path *`/tascaty`*:

Your Apache/WSGI server is doing the redirect. After the redirect to `/`, the client goes back to the ingress and the ingress doesn't know how to handle that so it will show you a *`404`*

#### What's happening with the ingress path *`/`*:

Your Apache/WSGI server is doing the redirect. After the redirect to `/`, the client goes back to the ingress and the ingress knows how to handle `/` and it all works great.

So both your ingress (which is running nginx) and Apache need to agree on the same path all the time. So you either use *`/`* on your ingress or you change your Apache configuration to also serve on *`/tascaty`* so that instead of redirecting to *`/`* it redirects to *`/tascaty`*.

Example of the latter:

```html
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>

        WSGIDaemonProcess tascaty_dev python-path=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages

        <Location /tascaty>
                WSGIProcessGroup tascaty_dev
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        </Location>

        WSGIScriptAlias /tascaty /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tascaty_project/wsgi.py
        <Directory /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tascaty_project/>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        Alias /tascaty/static /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/static
        <Directory /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, you need to remove this from the ingress manifest:

```yaml
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

✌️

Comment: Thanks Rico its working fine after doing the changes  but the pages are not displayed correctly

Comment: If you are using `/tascaty` you might have to add sections for both `/tascaty/` and `/tascaty` in your apache + ingress configs.