# Ingress path redirection, helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a service which is running in kubernetes, and has a path prefix `/api`. Now I want to use Ingress to access it through the host address `example.com/service1/` because I have multiple services. But the problem is that ingress redirects all the requests from path `service1/` with that prefix `service1/`, but I want it to redirect from `example.com/service1/` to my service with just `/` (so if I request `example.com/service1/api` it will redirect to service with just `/api`). Can I achieve something like this? I'm writing Ingress configuration in the helm chart of the service.
Ingress configuration in service chart file `values.yaml` looks like this:

```
...
ingress:
  enabled: true
  className: ""
  annotations: {}
  # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx // this comment was created when generating helm chart
  hosts:
    - host: example.com
      paths:
        - path: /service1(/|$)(.*)
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          backend:
            serviceName: $name
            servicePort: http
  tls: []
  ...
```

And `ingress.yaml` inside `templates/` folder is a default file that was generated by `helm` when I was creating a chart for the service. It just uses values from `values.yaml` to configure ingress. I didn't find anything, only [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63532836/kubernetes-ingress-not-redirecting-to-correct-path) which is basically saying that I need to add either prefix `service1/` to my service or just use `/api` in the Ingress configuration. But is there solution suitable for my needs?

Comment: Consider create an ingress to capture the prefix and redirect? https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#temporal-redirect

Comment: Take a look at this medium post: https://medium.com/ww-engineering/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-traffic-redirect-using-annotations-demystified-b7de846fb43d

Comment: @TonyYip, thanks, it helps, but what of these 4 options I should use? And how to redirect to service that is running in kubernetes, in the same namespace?

Comment: It is depends on what you need. I think method 1 example 2 may work for your case. Please note that the api client may not follow the redirection

Comment: @TonyYip, Thanks, I think I got it, you can post it as an answer and I will accept it if you want

Comment: if you use nginx you need to enable regex via annotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.*

Based on the solution provided in the comments (method 1 example 2 in the Medium [post](https://medium.com/ww-engineering/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-traffic-redirect-using-annotations-demystified-b7de846fb43d) ), a possible `values.yaml` file for Ingress might looks like below.

```
...
ingress:
  enabled: true
  className: ""
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: http://example.com/$2 
  hosts:
    - host: example.com
      paths:
        - path: /service1(/|$)(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: $name
            servicePort: http
  tls: []
  ...
```